# Is there any open source LAMP or Ruby on Rails cms using pure or declarative templates?

Tags: content-management-system, template-engine

And by that I mean something like [querytemplates](http://code.google.com/p/querytemplates/) or [effigy](https://github.com/jferris/effigy).

Another option would be a cms which encapsulates template rendering and is able to swap the default template engine for another one.

I'm not sure if something can be accomplished with XSL (Symphony CMS?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty broad question - do you have any constraints? E.g. OSS/Commercial? LAMP/WAMP/MS Stack?

Comment: LAMP, but I don't think I need to add more constraints. The main constraint is enough to reduce the amount of available answers to something near zero.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps mustache?

http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: mustache is just a logic-less templating language. I need a full cms solution.